# complex swap matrix 2D howa can i do

Tags: java, matrix

I need a some swap in my 2d array I need to swap all lines of matrix line by line for example

this is my matrix

```
{{1, 2, 3,4},
 {5, 6,4,8},
 {9,10,11,12},
```

and I need the result like this all permutation possible line by line and swap with specifier index

if index is 2 change 3,4 with 4,8

the is the result

```
{{1, 2, 4,8},    //swap(a[0][2]=a[1][2] and a[0][3]=a[1][3])
{5, 6,3,4},
{9,10,11,12},

{{1, 2, 11,12},  //swap(a[0][2]=a[2][2] and a[0][3]=a[2][3] )
{5, 6,3,4},
{9,10,4,8},

{{1, 2, 11,12},   //swap(a[1][2]=a[2][2] and a[1][3]=a[2][3])
{5, 6,4,8},
{9,10,3,4},

{{1, 2, 4,8},      //swap (a[1][2]=a[0][2]  and a[1][3]=a[0][3])
{5, 6,11,12},
{9,10,3,4},

........
```

for all permutation possible

But my code works just 2 line by 2 line in same matrix

```
public int[][] swap2D(int[][] array,int h){
    int tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(i%2==0){
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length ; j++) {
                if(j>h-1){
                    tmp = array[i][j];
                    array[i][j] = array[j-i][j];
                    array[j-i][j] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            // System.out.print(array[i][j] + ",");
        }
        //System.out.println("]");
    }
    return array;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you want transpose matrix??

Comment: No nit transpose . I need all permutation possible with this swap

Comment: If you want to return _all_ those possible swaps, your method needs to return a `List<int[][]>` or `int[][][]`